# Writing a wordpress plugin: add_meta_box vs. add_settings_field?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a custom wordpress plugin and trying to incorporate some functionality from a third-party plugin. That plugin seems to use `add_meta_box` to create the fields for settings options on the plugin admin pages.  I searched the entire source code of the plugin for `add_settings_field` and it doesn't occur once.  Are the two functions basically interchangeable?  From the WP Codex, it seems that add_meta_box is primarily for the purpose of adding "a custom section to the post and page editing screens" -- i.e. not so much intended for the admin settings/options forms.  On the other hand, the 3rd-party plugin seems to work very well, which is why I'm borrowing from it...

So in short my question is this: can someone please explain correct usage for the `add_meta_box` and `add_settings_field` functions?  Thanks!  Please let me know if anything about this question is unclear and I will do my best to rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is a settings field (Slug):

[image: setting field]

This is 2 Meta Boxes (publish and categories):

[image: meta boxes]